# Setting AWSDateTime for AppSync in AWS lambda function written in Python

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, aws-appsync, iso8601

I have a lambda function that needs to store an item in a DynamoDB table that is going to be used by AppSync. I want to add a createdAt and a updatedAt field to the item, as AWSDateTime types, and set them to the time of their creation. As explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html) I need to use An extended ISO 8601 date and time string in the format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ`. I use:

```py
import datetime from datetime
datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

but what it gives me is something like `2022-03-26T18:23:47Z` instead of `2022-03-26T18:23:47.210Z` for example (The three number-places after the second are absent).

Could you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milliseconds are optional.  Reduced precision formats are [valid ISO 8601 timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles) and thus valid `AWSDateTime` types.

If milliseconds are meaningful to your use case, there are several ways to add them:

```py
datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z'

# '2022-03-27T11:05:10.351Z'
```